# What is the best way to implement a GraphQL server in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

Currently, I'm building a graphQL backend for a client using the following-

- Node + Express
- Apollo server (apollo-server-express)
- MongoDB (with Mongoose ORM)

They have decided to go with **TypeScript** instead of JavaScript to write the backend.

I am new to TypeScript so I wanted to know the best tools/packages which I can use. On doing some research online I found out that I can use [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/). This package makes it really easy to work with GraphQL in TypeScript.

What is your opinion on this? It's a client's project so I wanted to be sure before moving forward with it.  Or can you suggest me a better tool/packages which can go well with the above list of packages?

Any links to resources will also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but StackOverflow isn't the best place to ask recommendations. It is a problem solving platform. That said, TypeGraphql is an excellent library, I have used it in two large projects. Go ahead with it. You will save a ton of typing.

Comment: TypeGraphQL works pretty good I can recommend it, otherwhise you can also use nestjs which also works pretty great.

Comment: Hey, @Nishant thanks for your inputs. As you said you had a good experience with TypeGraphql and you already used it in large projects, I guess I'll go with it. 

Do you have any sample projects using the same stack? That will help me structure my project properly (I'm new to this so it will be helpful)

Comment: Thanks @antoni_ku I'll have a look at nestjs too.

I already have an express-apollo backend. So I guess just adding TypeGraphql will be easier instead of starting with an entirely new framework. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this popular node framework [NestJS](https://nestjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script that generate GraphQL schema into types and write them into a single file. Then, you can import the types from the file where ever you need it. Also, you can pass the file to the frontend.